# Where can I find the data of the computer experiments in the book "Neural Networks and Learning Machines"?

Tags: reference-request, data-sets

The book ["Neural Networks and Learning Machines"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131471392) by Simon Haykin has many computer experiments to which many exercises are related. But there seems to be no data for these experiments available online. Where can I find them?

Comment: Have you tried to contact the authors?

Comment: There are plenty of datasets available for applying and testing machine learning algorithms. I'd have a look at: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MATLAB files for the book are accessible [here](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/haykin/).

I'm not familiar with the text, but there are `.mat` files in the zip named

> c.mat
>
> sig_lorenz_full.mat

which probably contain the data.  There are also a handful of TIFF files (images) from which he draws the other data.

Comment: There are also some in subfolders.